# JAXB Unmarshall to List

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall this XML to Java objects, a Customer object containing a List of EmailAdresses.

```
<customer>
 <emailAddresses>janed@example.com</emailAddresses>
 <emailAddresses>jdoe@example.org</emailAddresses>
</customer>
```

Having an issue with the list, I get the correct number of list items (2), but the value of the emailAddresses tag is null

**Customer.java**

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "customer" )
public class Customer
{
    private List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses;

    public Customer()
    {
        emailAddresses = new ArrayList<EmailAddress>();
    }

    public List<EmailAddress> getEmailAddresses()
    {
        return emailAddresses;
    }

    public void setEmailAddresses( List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses )
    {
        this.emailAddresses = emailAddresses;
    }
}
```

**EmailAddress.java**

```
public class EmailAddress
{
    private String emailAddresses;

    public String getEmailAddresses()
    {
        return emailAddresses;
    }

        public void setEmailAddresses( String emailAddresses )
    {
        this.emailAddresses = emailAddresses;
    }
}
```

**Failing Unit Test**

```
@Test
public void shouldDeserialiseCusomerXMLToObject() throws JAXBException
{
    String xml = "<customer>"
            + "    <emailAddresses>janed@example.com</emailAddresses>"
            + "    <emailAddresses>jdoe@example.org</emailAddresses>"
            + "</customer>";

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( Customer.class );
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    StringReader reader = new StringReader( xml );
    Customer msg = ( Customer ) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( reader );

    // This passes, I have 2 emailAddresses
    assertEquals( 2, msg.getEmailAddresses().size() );

    // This fails, I have a null pointer instead of the email address
    assertEquals( "janed@example.com", msg.getEmailAddresses().get( 0 ).getEmailAddresses() );
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding several annotations as per below, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `emailAddresses` field of `EmailAddress` is by default treated as a subelement, expecting the XML to be:

```
<customer>
    <emailAddresses>
        <emailAddresses>janed@example.com</emailAddresses>
    </emailAddresses>
    <emailAddresses>
        <emailAddresses>jdoe@example.org</emailAddresses>
    </emailAddresses>
</customer>
```

Since your outer `<emailAddresses>` element doesn't contain an inner `<emailAddresses>` element, the field is never assigned.

You want the `emailAddresses` field of `EmailAddress` to be the value of the (outer) `<emailAddresses>` element, so you have to tell `JAXB` that, by specifying the [`@XmlValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html) annotation:

```
@XmlValue
public String getEmailAddresses()
{
    return emailAddresses;
}
```

---

The `@XmlValue` annotation is especially useful when combined with [`@XmlAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html), to support XML like this:

```
<Person sex="male" age="25">John Doe</Person>
```

Where class would then be:

```
public class Person {
    public enum Sex {
        @XmlEnumValue("male")   MALE,
        @XmlEnumValue("female") FEMALE,
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    private Sex sex;
    @XmlAttribute
    private int age;
    @Value
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed explanation, really appreciated! Working great now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a level too many of email addresses.

If you should change the list of email addresses to a list of strings, like

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "customer" )
public class Customer
{
    private List<String> emailAddresses;

    public Customer()
    {
        emailAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public List<String> getEmailAddresses()
    {
        return emailAddresses;
    }

    public void setEmailAddresses( List<String> emailAddresses )
    {
        this.emailAddresses = emailAddresses;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant do that, as I also need to added some XML attributes to emailAddresses (omitted from code)